# Rails / ActiveRecord working with mysql BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems working with a mysql bit in Rails and ActiveRecord.
We store a bit for the published-state of Localities.

```
`published` bit(1) NOT NULL
```

I scaffolded it as `published:binary` in rails.

`Locality.first.published`returns `"\x01"`.

How do I get rails to treat this field as a boolean?

There is a staled Ticket but hacking ActiveRecord is not really an option. 
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6102-activerecord-boolean-support-with-bit1-mysql-data-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the attribute reader of your published attribute:

```
class Locality < ActiveRecord::Base
  # overwrite the attribute reader of the published attribute
  def published
    self.read_attribute(:published) == "\x01" ? true : false 
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Or generate a method for your boolean return value

```
class Locality < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_boolean
    self.published == "\x01" ? true : false
  end
end
```

So you can call:

```
 Locality.first.published.to_boolean => true || false
```

But I think the first solution (overwriting attribute reader) is better.

Comment: I have already thought about doing it that way, but it does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: and why not? why are you not using a normal boolean field instead of the bit?

Comment: I would have used a boolean instead of a bit but I think it would break some legacy applications that are still in use.

I just hoped to find a way around the comparison with "\x01" which could break sometime in the future.

Comment: well I understand. If you only want to work around the "\x01" I think the easiest way is to overwrite the attribute reader. Otherwise you´ll maybe have to change a lot of code overall your application, if the "\x01" will change to a normal boolean sometimes..

Answer (score 4):

Update for Rails 5: the new attributes API is made for handling situations just like this. First you define a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Type::Value`
 that handles `deserialize`ing from bit to boolean, and `cast`ing back from boolean to bit:

```
module Values
  class BitBoolean < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
    BIT_FALSE = "\x00"
    BIT_TRUE = "\x01"

    def cast(value)
      value ? BIT_TRUE : BIT_FALSE
    end

    def deserialize(value)
      value == BIT_TRUE
    end
  end
end
```

Then you define the attribute on your model with the `attribute` helper:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :published, Values::BitBoolean.new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres an extension method based on @Mattherick's answer above:

*lib/extensions/active_record/bit_boolean.rb*

```
module Extensions::ActiveRecord
  module BitBoolean
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class_methods do
      def alias_bit_to_boolean(attribute)
        define_method("#{attribute}?") do
          self.send(attribute) == "\x01" ? true : false
        end
      end
    end

  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Extensions::ActiveRecord::BitBoolean)
```

and require in an initializer:

*config/initializers/extensions.rb*

```
require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib/extensions/active_record/bit_boolean.rb')
```

Which then can be used:

```
class Locality < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_bit_to_boolean :published
end
```

This will produce a `locality.published?` method.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help @Mattherick.

With your help I have built something easier:

```
  def highlight
    self.read_attribute(:highlight) == "\x01" ? true : false
  end

  def highlight=(value)
    content_value = (value == false || value == 0 || value == "0") ? "\x00" : "\x01"
    self.write_attribute(:highlight,content_value)
  end
```

The `highlight` is the name of the field stored as `BIT` on database. And this solution also works with `checkbox` on view without the need of changes:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :highlight %>
    <%= f.check_box :highlight %>
  </div>
```